# ProgressBar's progress not working properly when activity starts

Tags: android, android-progressbar

I'm using an `ExpandableListActivity` and at the bottom I have a ProgressBar to determine how much lines were checked.

Activity's XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/activity_main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="100" >

    <include
        android:id="@+id/activity_checklist_titlebar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="10"
        layout="@layout/titlebar" />

    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="90" >
    </ExpandableListView>
</LinearLayout>

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/activity_checklist_progress"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/height_activity_checklist_progress"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/activity_checklist_progress_text"
        style="@style/Text.Strong.Medium"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/height_activity_checklist_progress"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="0/50" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I update the progress here:

```
@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{
    // ...
    TextView overall_progress_text = 
       (TextView) main_layout.findViewById(R.id.activity_checklist_progress_text);
        int overall_progress = checklist.getProgress();
        overall_progress_text.setText(overall_progress + "/" + checklist.size());
    ProgressBar overall_progress_bar = 
       (ProgressBar) main_layout.findViewById(R.id.activity_checklist_progress);
        overall_progress_bar.setProgress(overall_progress);
        overall_progress_bar.setMax(checklist.size());

    return convertView;
}
```

As you can see I have a TextView that shows the progress too, and apparently the values are fine. Everything works fine too when I start to change the checkboxes' state in the list, the only problem is at the start of the activity.

The progressBar shows this (I think the max value is taking '100' instead of '9'):

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I simply solved my problem setting the max value before the progress. It seems Android's ProgressBar doesn't work even if you set the max right after the progress...

Changed this:

```
overall_progress_bar.setProgress(overall_progress);
overall_progress_bar.setMax(checklist.size());
```

To this:

```
overall_progress_bar.setMax(checklist.size());
overall_progress_bar.setProgress(overall_progress);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use  [Async Task](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) to view progress and in [onProgressUpdate](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onProgressUpdate%28Progress...%29) u can put a progress dialog or a progress bar..